# ID won't show up on template

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to save a model object that has an auto-increment id and then get that ID and use it in a template. The id won't show up though.

Here's the code that processes the submission:

```
def process_submission(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
            submission=request.POST
            temp = Listing(title=submission['title'],pub_date=datetime.datetime.now(),email=submission['email'],price=submission['price'],body=submission['body'],subject=submission['subject'],course_number=submission['course_number'])
            temp.save()
            return render(request, 'listing/success.html', {'temp', temp})
```

And then the relevant part of success.html

```
<p>Submission Successful!</p>
<p>You can find your listing at: <a href="blah/{{temp.id}}">URL/{{temp.id}}</a></p>
```

The ID won't show up. I'm not quite sure why this isn't working. Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Edit:

Here is the model in question:

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('Date Published')
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=1500)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    course_number = models.CharField(max_length=4)

    def __str__(self):
            return self.title
```

Comment: I think for you to be able to use `temp` as a context in your template it will need to be outside the `if` block. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Can you add your model to the question?

Comment: Your code would work almost 100% if request method is `POST`. However, unless you didn't show your full view method, you didn't handle the case where request method is `GET`. What's the behavior for `GET` request?

Comment: I added the model. I don't have a request method for GET because (at the moment) there's no reason to GET this page.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, code you mentioned above should work. Check this document: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#auto-incrementing-primary-keys, and please make sure that you;re using AutoField as id.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set `primary_key=True` on one of the other fields in your model? If so Django will not automatically provide an `id` field. Or perhaps you declared your own field named `id`? If you do have another valid primary key in your model, you could use that in your template rather than Django's autoincremented id.

Try printing out the value of `id` after saving the record in your view.

Comment: No, I haven't set any other primary_keys or have my own field named id.

Comment: I suppose I could set another primary key and do all the listings that way but I'd rather keep the naming scheme that I have currently.

Comment: What was the result of printing out `temp.id` after `temp.save()`? Was a record actually created in your db, and was a corresponding valid `id` created? Are other fields from your model available in your template, e.g. can you display `temp.title`?